# Difference between / and /mnt/upgrade if mounted on different partitions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, embedded-linux, mount

I have a 512 MB NAND flash which has 7 partitions. The rootfs of UBIFS type is mounted on 4th partition (mtdblock03). It also has an upgrade partition of UBIFS type and mounted on 6th partition (mtdblock06). The information displayed after `mount` command is :

```
root@freescale ~$ mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
ubi0:gpmi-nfc-general-use on / type ubifs (rw,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
rwfs on /mnt/rwfs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=512k)
ubi1:upgrade on /mnt/upgrade type ubifs (rw,relatime)
```

My question is, when upgrade is on `/mnt/upgrade`, weather it will not be a part of `/`. 
As whole of the `/` is in (mtdblock03), so /mnt/upgrade shall be a part of (mtdblock03) rather than (mtdblock06)?

Comment: can you post the contents of /proc/partitions ?

Comment: yes, here is the o/p :

`major minor  #blocks  name  
 31        0       4096 mtdblock0  
 31        1       10240 mtdblock1  
 31        2       10240 mtdblock2  
 31        3     127100 mtdblock3   
 31        6      83968 mtdblock6   
 254       0     127100 ubiblka     
 254       8      80104 ubiblkb `

Comment: @golimar : i tried but i am not able to correct its format.

Comment: You can edit the original post with the formatted output. Also can you do a 'df' or 'df -h' ?

Comment: You are misusing the verb `mount`.  It reads like "fish eat you" instead of "you eat fish".  *"/ is mounted on (mtdblock03)"* should be "mtdblock03 is mounted on /".  The filesystem (or the device that holds that fs) is *mounted* on a directory acting as the mount point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `/mnt/upgrade` is **NOT** part of `mtdblock03`.

`/` and `/mnt/upgrade` are all virtual points in a virtual filesystem, which is only a  virtual map to the underlying physical media (NAND-flash in your case).

Look at it this way :

### 1. When the system boots

Initially using the kernel bootargs `rootfs=`,
the entire filesystem `/` is be mounted.
At this point in time, `mtdblock03` (pointed to by `ubi0`) is mounted to `/`.

[image: initial rootfs mounted]

- Anything written anywhere under `/` ends up in `mtdblock03`.

### 2. Later

Either manually or using init scripts,
`mtdblock06` (pointed to by `ubi1`) is mounted,
at `/mnt/upgrade`.

[image: another block mounted]

- Now anything written under `/` **EXCEPT** under `/mnt/upgrade` ends up in `mtdblock03`.
  And anything written under `/mnt/upgrade` ends up in `mtdblock06`.

As long as the second `mount` is not unmounted (using `umount`),

> **all I/O to `/mnt/upgrade` is redirected to `mtdblock06`**

and **NOT** `mtdblock03`.

---

<sub>1. In the above figures, the **red dotted-line** represents the 1st mount command (rootfs) and the **blue dotted-line** represents the second mount command (/mnt/update). Both establish a filesystem mapping with the underlying device i.e the NAND-flash.</sub>

<sub>2. The `mount` command basically establishes a virtual map i.e. your filesystem that represents various parts of the physical device(s) present on the system.</sub>

<sub>3. Also the `mount` command will over-ride any earlier `mount` command that maps the same node on the filesystem. Hence, any node on the filesystem represents the physical device as pointed to by the last executed `mount` command that references the node or its parent.</sub>

<sub>4. In the interests of keeping things simple, the figures show a direct mapping. In reality, there are multiple drivers involved; namely the **vfs**, **ubifs** and the **nand** drivers that sit in between the filesystem and the underlying physical media.</sub>

Comment: Thankyou for well detailed answer and clarifying my doubt.